# htaccess redirect from singular directory to plural directory

Tags: .htaccess

I'll highly appreciate everyone who can help to redirect the follow example:

from

```
www.example.com/topic/123/
```

to

```
www.example.com/topics/123/
```

I tried with many patterns, conditions, tutorial ... but with no result

In my opinion the next one should work, but unfortunately it doesn't

```
RewriteRule ^topic/(.*)/$ /topics/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Why do you have a trailing slash on the pattern for your RewriteRule?

Comment: I'm sorry I just forgot to write the final slashes in the example, but does it matter really whether there is or no a slash before ending symbol $ ?

Comment: I just removed the slash at the end and the pattern is working as I expected. I can't believe after so much time wondering. Thanks man! I appreciate it :)

Comment: so the right syntax of my example is RewriteRule ^topic/(.*)$ /topics/$1 [L,R=301]